# Pulling POSIXt dates into another dataframe as new columns based on row index in another dataframe - reproducible

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, posixct, indices

I have the dataframe "df1" below which contains row indices that relate to the rows of data frame "df".

I want to use the row indices in df1 to bring in the corresponding row in the dataframe df. i.e., the first row df1 is 4 and 6 and I want to create two new columns in df1 that are start time (timestamp on row 4 of df) and end time (timestamp on row 6 of df).

Actual dataframes are much longer so general code to do this would help

```
df1 <- structure(list(co2_start = c(4, 6, 9, 12), co2_end = c(6, 9, 
12, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
    
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1623481200, 1623481500, 1623481800, 
    1623482100, 1623482400, 1623482700, 1623483000, 1623483300, 1623483600, 
    1623483900, 1623484200, 1623484500, 1623484800, 1623485100, 1623485400
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I would like df1 to look like below

```r
4     6     2021-06-12 00:15:00     2021-06-12 00:25:00
6     9     2021-06-12 00:25:00     2021-06-12 00:40:00
9     12    2021-06-12 00:40:00     2021-06-12 00:55:00
12    15    2021-06-12 00:55:00     2021-06-12 01:10:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `df1` are already row indices, you can just use `dplyr::mutate()` to create your columns and subset with the values in start/end columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(co2_start = c(4, 6, 9, 12), co2_end = c(6, 9, 12, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1623481200, 1623481500, 1623481800, 1623482100, 1623482400, 1623482700, 1623483000, 1623483300, 1623483600, 1623483900, 1623484200, 1623484500, 1623484800, 1623485100, 1623485400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

df1 %>% 
  mutate(start = df$date[co2_start],
         end = df$date[co2_end])
#>   co2_start co2_end               start                 end
#> 1         4       6 2021-06-12 07:15:00 2021-06-12 07:25:00
#> 2         6       9 2021-06-12 07:25:00 2021-06-12 07:40:00
#> 3         9      12 2021-06-12 07:40:00 2021-06-12 07:55:00
#> 4        12      15 2021-06-12 07:55:00 2021-06-12 08:10:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>